# Is it possible to put resource limits on an IIS7 site?

Tags: iis-7, web-server, web, web-applications, rate-limiting

I have a number of different web apps running under IIS7.  Is it possible to put limits on one app - for example, limit the number of connections, bandwidth, memory usage and CPU allowed?

I need to do this without installing any additional software on the box.

Answer (score 1):

Advanced Setting --> Behavior --> and then break down connection limits:

You'll see connection limits, connection time out, and max bandwidth settings as well.

This can be done per app.

Answer (score 1):

You can also at the Application Pool level (process) limit the memory consumption and 
Server->Application Pools->(select)->Advanced Settings->  CPU Limit, Queue Length, Memory Limit, etc.